# Oracle SQL - One query gives the correct output while the other, very similar, query does not. Why?

Tags: sql, date, select, oracle12c

This query is executing and giving correct output:

```
select * from emp where hiredate > '15-11-81'
```

But this query is not giving correct output:

```
select * from emp where hiredate > '01-01-11'
```

Why?

Comment: To help you out, please put the output of the query that works, then put the error message of the query that does not work

Comment: Do you compare string with date? Shouldn't it be `to_date('15-11-81','dd-mm-yy')` instead of `'15-11-81'`

Comment: first query is giving 6 rows as output , but second query is not giving any output and any error also

Comment: i tried using to_date function also

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
 select * from emp where hiredate > '01-01-11'
```

have no data. you need to share the Table data with query and table definition.

Comment: 7839 KING PRESIDENT  17-11-81 5000  10
7698 BLAKE MANAGER 7839 01-05-81 2850  30
7782 CLARK MANAGER 7839 09-06-81 2450  10
7566 JONES MANAGER 7839 02-04-81 2975  20
7788 SCOTT ANALYST 7566 19-04-87 3000  20
7902 FORD ANALYST 7566 03-12-81 3000  20
7369 SMITH CLERK 7902 17-12-80 800  20
7499 ALLEN SALESMAN 7698 20-02-81 1600 300 30
7521 WARD SALESMAN 7698 22-02-81 1250 500 30
7654 MARTIN SALESMAN 7698 28-09-81 1250 1400 30
7844 TURNER SALESMAN 7698 08-09-81 1500 0 30
7876 ADAMS CLERK 7788 23-05-87 1100  20
7900 JAMES CLERK 7698 03-12-81 950  30
7934 MILLER CLERK 7782 23-01-82 130

Comment: you should do like this:

Comment: how to get the data by comparing dates

Comment: your date data type is nvarchar. you should convert it into date.

Comment: use  Convert(datetime,HireDate)

Comment: yaa, i used already. It is not showing any error but it gives empty table output.i don't know why it is vary for different dates

Comment: First to all you need to convert the HireDate column to datetime by changing definition after that try your query.

Comment: select * from emp where hiredate > to_date('01-01-11','dd-mm-yy')
is taking the date with 20 th century ,so it is not giving output.but the below query is giving output
select * from emp where hiredate > to_date('01-01-1911','dd-mm-yyyy')

Comment: yes, because 11 as year is taking year of 2011 not 1911. use this  select * from emp where hiredate > to_date('01-01-1911','dd-mm-yyyy')

Comment: finally great. Can you please check the answers is useful to you  ~Cheers